# Hamilton-Jacobi equation and Action Functional

Tags: hamilton-equations, hamilton-jacobi-equation

Let the *action functional* $S[q]$ given by
\begin{equation}\label{eq16}
    S[q]=\int\limits^{t_2}_{t_1}L\left(q^i(t),\dot{q}^i(t)\right)dt
\end{equation}
Also, we know that using Legendre Transform the hamiltonian $H(q^i,p_i)$ is related with $L(q^i,\dot{q}^i)$ by
\begin{equation}
    L(q^i,\dot{q}^i)=p_i q^i - H(q^i,p_i) \quad \text{with} \quad p_i=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}^i}
\end{equation}
Thus, replacing this last equation inside the action function we have
\begin{align}\label{eq105}
    S(q,t)&=\int\limits^t_{t_0}p_i(t)\dot{q}^i(t)dt-\int\limits^t_{t_0}H(q^i(t),p_i(t))dt\\
    S(q,t)&=\int\limits^{q(t)}_{q(t_0)}p_i(t)dq^i-\int\limits^t_{t_0}H(q^i(t),p_i(t))dt
\end{align}
Finally, we also know the diferential form of $S(q,t)$ is by definition
\begin{equation}\label{eq110}
    dS(q^i,t)=\frac{\partial S(q^i,t)}{\partial q^i}dq^i + \frac{\partial S(q^i,t)}{\partial t}dt
\end{equation}
wich give us these following relations
\begin{equation}
    p_i=\frac{\partial S(q^i,t)}{\partial q^i} \quad \text{and} \quad -H(q^i,p_i)=\frac{\partial S(q^i,t)}{\partial q^i}
\end{equation}
Replacing $p_i$ relation inside $H$ give us the **Hamilton-Jacobi equation**
\begin{equation}\label{eq116}
    \frac{\partial S(q^i,t)}{\partial t}+H\left(q^i,\frac{\partial S(q^i,t)}{\partial q^i}\right)=0
\end{equation}

**Question** When working with action functional we already know that physical motions are those curves that are the an extremum of $S[q]$. But here we actually wrote $S[q]$ as a function $S(q,t)$ of $(q,t)$ and this give us Hamilton-Jacobi equation. My question is: every solution of Hamilton-Jacobi equation is an extremum of $S[q]$ ? Also, there's an relation (even conceptually) between extremum of $S[q]$ and general solutions of Hamilton-Jacobi equation?